# Authentication Issue using PassportJS google OAUTH2.0

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-oauth, passport.js

I am trying to implement a passport oAuth login and signup API that will save a user to MongoDB on signup and login to an existing user.. I used my google mail accounts(3 of them) for testing but for some reason, it only signup and login to only one of my mail and then sends an error on an attempt to signup the other accounts. below is the passport code and controller code

controller code

```
    async function ssoLogin(req, res, next){

    // declare token;
    let token;

    // declare rider with sso login
    let riderSSO;

    try{
        const { _raw, _json, ...userProfile } = req.user;
        console.log(userProfile)

        //validate sso details that will be added into model
        const { error } = ssovalidateRider({
            email: userProfile.emails[0].value.toLowerCase().trim(),
            firstName: userProfile.name.familyName,
            lastName: userProfile.name.givenName,
            googleId: userProfile.id
        });
        if (error)
            return res.status(400).json({
                error: error.details[0].message,
            });

       
        // check if a user is already existing...
        riderSSO= await RiderModel.findOne({googleId: userProfile.id});

        if(riderSSO){
            // create a Token
            token= riderSSO.generateAuthToken(riderSSO._id, riderSSO.email)
            delete riderSSO['__v'];
        }else{
            // Register new user here
            riderSSO = await RiderModel.create({
                // email: _json.email.toLowerCase().trim(),
                email: userProfile.emails[0].value.toLowerCase().trim(),
                googleId: userProfile.id,
                firstName: userProfile.name.familyName,
                lastName: userProfile.name.givenName
            });

            // create a Token
            token= riderSSO.generateAuthToken(riderSSO._id, riderSSO.email)
            delete riderSSO['__v'];
        }
        

        res.status(201).json({
            status: 'success',
            data: req.user,
            token,
            data: riderSSO
        });

    }catch(err){
        console.log(err)
        res.status(400).json({
            sucess:'fail',
            message: `unable to login or signup ${err}`,
        });
    }
}
```

passport config code:

```
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
clientID: process.env.CLIENT_1_ID,
clientSecret: process.env.CLIENT_1_SECRET,
callbackURL: "http://localhost:4000/api/v1/rider/google/callback",
proxy: true
}, (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
console.log(accessToken);
return done(null, profile)
}));
```

error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null
at model.mongodbErrorHandler (C:\Users\peter\Desktop\driveme-backend-master\node_modules\mongoose-mongodb-errors\lib\plugin.js:19:49)
at callMiddlewareFunction (C:\Users\peter\Desktop\driveme-backend-master\node_modules\kareem\index.js:482:23)
at next (C:\Users\peter\Desktop\driveme-backend-master\node_modules\kareem\index.js:163:9)
at Kareem.execPost (C:\Users\peter\Desktop\driveme-backend-master\node_modules\kareem\index.js:217:3)
at _handleWrapError (C:\Users\peter\Desktop\driveme-backend-master\node_modules\kareem\index.js:245:21)
at _cb (C:\Users\peter\Desktop\driveme-backend-master\node_modules\kareem\index.js:304:16)
at C:\Users\peter\Desktop\driveme-backend-master\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:341:9
at C:\Users\peter\Desktop\driveme-backend-master\node_modules\kareem\index.js:135:16
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11)
```